# How to make echo a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

when I attempt to echo these names, nothing comes up...

```
//  
$getuser = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE account_id = $id";     
$showuser = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $getuser); // Run the query.

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($showuser, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

 $names[]=$row['user_username'];

 }


echo $names;
```

Answer (score 4):

To Echo an Array use

```
print_r($names)
```

Echo will only print out a simple variable (Text, Number).  `print_r` is used to format and print out complex types such as arrays and objects.

Further information can be found on the php.net website.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of echo use print_r.

```
print_r($names);
```

Like that.

Answer (score -1):

you should initialize $names as array before the while loop `$names = array();`